# Create the voronoi diagram with openCv and C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-segmentation, voronoi

I have a little problem. I need to create the voronoi diagram of a BW image by using openCV and C++. I should have something like the output of the Matlab function voronoin.

The goal is to create a mask for each region of the diagram.

This is an example I made in Matlab:

[matlab voronoi diagram](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=860401Voronoi.png)

So, for each region I should create a mask or to have a different color.
I tried the openCV function distanceTransform in order to get the voronoi labels.

```
Mat bwCoresGoodInv = 255 - bwCoresGood;
distanceTransform(bwCoresGoodInv, distTr,voronoiLabels, CV_DIST_L2, CV_DIST_MASK_PRECISE, DIST_LABEL_PIXEL);

namedWindow( "voronoiDistLab", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
voronoiLabels = voronoiLabels*5;
imshow( "voronoiDistLab", voronoiLabels );
```

the results is the following image:
[voronoi labels openCV](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=776373VoronoiDist.png)

as you can see in each region there are differents colors(in particular there is something in correspondence to the cell), is there a way to have just a color?
thank you in advance

Comment: The image links are dead. You can upload your images on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to get different colors than the gray scale values provided by displaying the labels, one approach (probably not the most efficient) is to run `cv::findContours` on an edge-detected image of the label image, and then iterate through each contour found and draw it onto a new image, it can be filled or outlined.  It's not super exact and can leave gaps, some dilation on the edge image may be required.

It would be very nice if distanceTransform returned a data-structure that mapped the range of intensity values in the label image to every pixel that has that value, maybe with a vector of binary images where the nth image in the vector is a binary mask with an isolated nth label region- but I think as it is now this would have to be done by the user.